# Sublime Text: How do you exit the multiple row layout

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, text-editor

I was wondering how you exit the multiple row layout on Sublime Text. I switched to a 3 row layout when editing one of my Django projects, but how do I exit from it (remove the extra rows I have added).

Thanks,
Henry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use View -> Layout menu. If you choose View -> Layout -> Single, other rows will be removed. Short keys depends on OS.

Answer (score 2):

In the menu bar: View > Layout > Single

Or from the keyboard (on Windows): Alt + Shift + 1

To find your default shortcuts, Preferences > Key Bindings - Default, and search for `"set_layout"`.

Comment: Shortcuts can be seen on menu as well.